# Sending an image over socket networking

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcp

I'm currently doing a small project, creating a conference application using tcp network sockets.

I'm finding it quite hard to encode and decode strings and sending the data from the server to the clients. I am trying to send a picture box image to the clients.

Methods and statements involved within the process: (drawBox is the picturebox)

```
    private void SaveSnapshot()
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(drawBox.ClientSize.Width, drawBox.ClientSize.Height);
        drawBox.DrawToBitmap(bmp, drawBox.ClientRectangle);
        OnUpdatedDrawing(ImageToBase64(bmp, ImageFormat.Bmp));
    };
    public string ImageToBase64(Bitmap image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Convert Image to byte[]
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to base 64 string
            string base64String = Convert.ToString(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
    private void Drawboard_OnUpdatedDrawing(string data)
    {
        BroadCast("Draw|" + data);
    }
    private void BroadCast(string data)
    {
        foreach(var socket in Clients)
        {
            try { socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)); }
            catch (SocketException SE) { MessageBox.Show("Error: " + SE.Message, "Error"); }
        }
    }

            case "Draw":
                this.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    byte[] NewBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(command[1]); // Contains the base 64 string of the picture box bitmap
                    MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
                    Drawboard.drawBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms1);
                    Drawboard.drawBox.Refresh();
                });
```

Error: Parameter is not valid. Where the error is coming from:

```
    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        try
        {
            var buffer = (byte[])AR.AsyncState;
            var receive = _Socket.EndReceive(AR);

            if (receive != 0)
            {
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, receive);
                this.OnReceived(this, data);
            }
            else
            {
                this.OnDisconnected(this);
                this.isConnected = false;
                this.Close();
                return;
            }

            this._Socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReadCallback, buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnErrorReceived(this, ex.Message + "\n\nError connecting to the server");
        }
    }
```

[GUI Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMoYI.png)

Comment: Why don't you just send the image as binary data? There's no need to convert it to base64 first. Also, you need to tell the receiver how many bytes to expect or tag the data in a way that the receiver can discern the message length. There's no guarantee that the image will come in all at once.

Comment: How would i go about doing that? Thanks

Comment: There are countless tutorials on how to do this. Maybe google "c# send binary data over socket".

Comment: Your `imageBytes` is already a byte array, so just send this instead of converting it to a Base64 string and then converting the string to a byte array.

Comment: var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, receive); - This lines causes the error. I guess its not encoding right

Comment: the received bytes will be saved ar.AsyncState.workSocket.buffer; You can't do like `var buffer = (byte[])AR.AsyncState;`, AsyncState is `A user-defined object that qualifies or contains information about an asynchronous operation.`, not one byte[].

Comment: check this: [The code example ends a pending asynchronous read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry to ask but do you have team viewer? haha